# Exposing a docker container to the internet

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding, docker

I deployed a ghost blogging platform on my server using docker. Now I want to expose it to the internet but I'm having some difficulties doing so.

I opened port `8080` in my router a forwarded it to port `8080` which is the one assign to that container. Using port `8080` inside my network I can access the website fine but when I try to access it from the internet it gives took too long to respond error.

Local IP + PORT: `http://10.0.0.140:8080/`

**Port tester**

[image]

**Router settings**

[image]

**Portainer**

[image]
[image]
[image]

This post was transferred from [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66527816/exposing-a-docker-container-to-the-internet).

Comment: I doubt that you will be able to access your website from the internet...

Comment: Which operating system and which `docker run` command are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu server. I'm running a proxmox VM with ubuntu server with docker @harrymc

Comment: why? @user79161

Comment: Which `docker run` command?

Comment: @harrymc used portrainer app template.

Comment: @harrymc also using bridge dont know if that makes a difference but I'm using bridge for network.

Comment: @harrymc Added the portainer config to the post

Comment: How did you test the port forwarding? From inside your network? This may not work. Try from a mobile phone (W-Fi disabled of course) or something else outside your network.

Comment: Used port tester https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ @DanielB

Comment: If I understand right the port-forwarding, it's like this:  8000 -> 32769, Docker: 8080 -> 2368. I don't see the connection between them. I would expect something like: Router: 8000 -> 8000, Docker: 8000 -> 2368 (or 2369?). If I misunderstood the configuration, please explain.

Comment: Its 8080 -> 8080 -> 8080 -> 2368
I changed due to a post in StackOverflow but didn't fix
@harrymc

Comment: Better post new screenshots if this has changed.

Comment: @harrymc images updated

Comment: ITS WORKING. Dont know wy but used my phone and it worked

Comment: It will be difficult to write an answer here...